# xamarin android DatePickerDialog set mini date

Tags: android, xamarin, datepickerdialog

I'm using DatePickerDialog and i want to hide every date before today.
I can hide previous month and year using this code:

```
dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = new Java.Util.Date().Time - 1000;
```

But it's not working like i want. Days between 1st of june and today are disabled (gray) but we still can click on them and dismiss the dialog by clicking on the positive button.

Does someone has a solution to realy disabled them ? or at least avoid dismiss the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give MinDate the number of milliseconds between your minimum date (in your case today) and January 1st 1970, so:

```
dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = (long)(DateTime.Today.Date - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

This should prevent users from selecting any earlier dates.

Comment: Can you share the code that's creating the date picker dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the mindate to date now?

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Something like that should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//for lesser than today
dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();

//for greater than today
dialog.DatePicker.MaxDate = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
```

This solved mine :)